# How much storage space does a fully synced node need?

Tags: go-ethereum

I'm planning on launching a virtual machine for Ethereum development, but I have no idea how much storage space to allocate to it. Can anyone tell me how much storage space a fully synced node uses?

Comment: If you mean a non-archive (full) node then I think it's around 100-200GB. If you mean some lighter sync modes then it's much less.

Comment: It was already asked many times. Etherscan keeps a chart with some clients info https://etherscan.io/chartsync/chaindefault